# How can I stop smooth scrolling 80px before the div since I am using fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

I am using a script for scroll to div function. And now I have stuck my header as fixed on the top, since I want it sticky. But now when I click the div link, it goes below the header, since the header is fixed. Can I stop the scrolling 80px before the actual div?

This is the code I am using.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top 
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="js/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var $elem = $('#content');

        $('#nav_up').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#nav_down').fadeIn('slow');  

        $(window).bind('scrollstart', function(){
            $('#nav_up,#nav_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.2'});
        });
        $(window).bind('scrollstop', function(){
            $('#nav_up,#nav_down').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
        });

        $('#nav_down').click(
            function (e) {
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
            }
            );
        $('#nav_up').click(
            function (e) {
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
            }
            );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you just pad the div that you're scrolling to down by 80px?

Comment: @NickRobins I can, but that is ruining the design.

Comment: @NickRobins That is why I am wanting that the scrolling stops 80px before the div.

Answer (score 1):

you can minus header height from top offset of scrolling div

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the `80px` off the `scrollTop` value:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80;
}, 1000);
```

I would suggest you make this more dynamic though, should the height of the header change for any reason:

```
var headerHeight = $('#myHeader').height();
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. By any chance, can I specify a different height for a mobile screen?

Comment: If you set the height of the header in CSS using a media query, the second code example will automatically do that for you.

Comment: That is working fine buddy. But what happens is, on a mobile screen it takes the height of the header after the burger menu opens, and not when it is closed.

Comment: Hi! I have similar case. I tried to implement your code into my code, but it doesn't work. Can I share with you of my code for you to see how to implement your code into mine? Thks!